# How to remap combinations of keys including the windows key?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, bluetooth, keyboard-layout

To avoid the XY problem, I'll explain my problem and then the problem I have with my attempted solutions:

## Problem

I have a windows laptop (hp elitebook), and I use my wireless bluetooth mac keyboard with it.  Because the keyboard shortcuts do not translate well from windows to Mac, I want to remap them.  I can either 1) remap the keys on the windows machine, such that the bluetooth mapping is what I desire, or 2) remap the keys on the bluetooth wireless keyboard.

I chose 1) because I want to be able to use my bluetooth wireless keyboard with other machines.

## Attempted Solution

Let's say, for example I want to map the `cntrl+W` to `Windows key+W`.  I can't just map `Cntrl` to `Windows key`, because I need the `cntrl` key for other things.  I want to map the *combination* to another *combination*.

I tried this `SharpKeys` , but it only maps single keys to single keys.
I tried `Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator`, which looked promising, but in the layout interface, there is no windows key (strange, since it came from Microsoft).
I even tried editting the `.klc` file, which is what [this guy](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/08/how-to-fix-keyboard-shortcuts-in-klc-eg.html) suggested, but I found it very difficult to edit the `.klc` files for my purpose.  The `klc` files can be downloaded using the Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator, and the codes for the keys can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927178.aspx).  But , even still I do not know how to edit it to allow *combations* of keys, again it seems like it is only good for one to one.

Any suggestions for the Problem or the Attempted Solution?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done via [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/).

Once you've downloaded and installed AHK, open a black Notepad and enter `^w::#w`. Then save the file as `fileName.ahk` and double click to run it. Pressing `ctrl+w` will now send `WindowsLogoKey+w`. This can be done with as many shortcut keys as you'd like and can be used to create complex shortcuts, hotkeys, and hotstrings as well.

Comment: This works for remapping `key combinations` on my windows machine.  i.e. when I remap `ctrl+w` to `windowslogokey+w`, I can close tabs in chrome with `windowslogokey+w`.  However, when I use my bluetooth wireless mac keyboard, the remapping does not work.  The "command" button on the MacKeyboard means "windowslogokey", but it doesn't remap on my MacKeyboard.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You most likely need to use the Key's Scan Code. See "Special Keys" section here: https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm